# Why isn't my Azure Mobile Service accepting the bearer token ADAL.js is sending it?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, adal

I am using ADAL.js with implicit flow to authenticate an AngularJS app to be able to access an Azure Mobile Services API.

I have set up Azure AD identity information in the Identity tab of the AMS (azure mobile service) as follows...

The app url is set to: https://<>.azure-mobile.net/login/aad

The client id is the client id from the application set up in the Azure AD.

The allowed tenant is: <>.onmicrosoft.com

The header is included in the GET request: Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi...

But I get a 401 response from AMS.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

UPDATE:
It looks like I would have to call into the AMS end point passing the Azure AD access_token to get a AMS token. And I get this response:

> {"code":401,"error":"Error: Authentication with 'windowsazureactivedirectory' is not supported."}

So, I guess I will have to go with the service directed login as specified https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn283952.aspx

Perhaps some day this will be supported for the javascript back end. But, the more I do with AMS the more it looks like I should have gone with a .net backend.

UPDATE 05/29

I changed my AMS to a .Net backend so I could use client directed flow. I am using the following code:

```
client.login('aad', { "access_token": sessionStorage['adal.idtoken'] })
            .done(function (results) {
                alert("You are now logged in as: " + results.userId);
                sessionStorage.X_ZUMO_AUTH = results.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken;
            }, function (err) {
                alert("Error: " + err);
            });
```

However, I am getting a 401 response.

UPDATE: Based on another SO issue I have created a second app in the Azure AD for the client. I have set it to allow access to the API app. I also updated my code to the following:

```
          adalService.acquireToken('<<AMS App Client ID>>')
            .then(function(token) {

                $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: constants.apiBaseUrl + '/login/aad', 
                        data: { "access_token" : token },
                        headers: {
                            'X-ZUMO-APPLICATION': constants.appKey
                        }
                      }).                
                    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        alert(data);
                    }).
                    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        alert(data);
                    });                        
            });
    }
```

But, I still get a 401. I also tried it with the mobile sdk, still a 401.

Comment: for the record, and completeness: 1) the right endpoint where to post is /login/aad, and not /login/windowsazureactivedirectory; but still this returns an explicit error message that POSTing an access token isn't allowed in this case.   2) when using the Mobile Service JS SDK authenticating an AAD user works correctly

Comment: Right, I was able to get the service directed authentication to work. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn283952.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to another SO member who posted a blog on how to do this exact thing...

http://blogs.if-blueprint.de/svenor/2015/06/19/authenticate-azure-mobile-service-app-adal-js/

...which pointed to a link that allowed me to solve it.

My problem was that the app id url on the client AAD application was not in a verified domain on the Azure Active Directory. I was using https://mysite.azurewebsites.net.

When I changed it to a url that was in the domain https://mydomainname.onmicrosoft.com/myappname then it just worked like magic.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're following the right steps. Could you take a look at the how to on Azure's website to see if you're missing anything? Could you share the client code you use to login?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-how-to-use-client-library/#caching

Comment: thanks, looks like this isn't supported with a javascript backend. See my update above.

Comment: You are correct. The JavaScript backend doesn't yet support client direct AAD login.

Comment: Why Chris why? Any plans to support this. I see Javascript back end web api apps aren't even in the new portal... are they going to be dropping this?

Comment: We likely won't support this because we're working on the next evolution of Mobile Services - Mobile Apps - and have all our Node folks working full steam on that. With Mobile Apps, we have a better tie in story with Azure Websites and we make it WAY easier to release new features; so get excited about some new stuff coming up, but Mobile Services won't likely see any drastic improvements. We still haven't made any plans on retiring it, though, so feel free to use it if it meets your scenario. Feel free to email me with any questions/concerns - chrande (at) microsoft (dot) com.

Comment: got it. So, is the new Mobile App in the new portal the equivalent to a mobile service in the old portal, but only supporting a .Net backend?

Comment: That's correct. Node.js backend is in the works right now, plus quick a bit of portal UI changes are likely.

Comment: Ok, I changed to a .Net backend so I could use the client directed flow... I can getting the error specified. Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79160/discussion-between-chris-anderson-and-pilotbob).

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that the 401 comes from the fact that ADAL.JS is presenting an ID token which is different in structure from the access token which Mobile Services expects. The client directed flow in Mobile Services was built around the earlier ADAL clients for native mobile platforms, and these have full access tokens that they can present.

One of the main things that Mobile Servicer checks for in the access token is that the audience of the token is the /login/aad endpoint, but this is not true of ID tokens.

Based on what I am seeing, I do not think ADAL.JS is supported by Mobile Services at this time. It doesn't appear that you can get the access token needed for the client-directed flow. Your best bet is to use the server flow, which it sounds like you have working.

Comment: I was wrong here - it turns out this is doable, as evidenced by another SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642138/authenticate-against-an-azure-mobile-service-app-with-adal-js-acquired-token/30646217#30646217

Comment: Yes, I'm following all those steps and still getting a 401. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.